# Trying to use Ubuntu 16.10 desktop to diagnose USB hardware issue

Tags: usb

I suspect that my USB ports have failed in my laptop.  Plugging in devices (phone or GPSr) powers them up and charges the phone.  However, I am unable to read USB drives or use my USB mouse.  Ubuntu was suggested as a tool that might be able to check the physical ports, so I have it on a DVD and I am able to boot into Ubuntu, but that is as far as I am able to do on my own without assistance.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 1):

The command `lsusb` will provide output identifying hardware connected to your USB ports. For example if I plug a flash drive into a port on my system I get output like this:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8564:1000 Transcend Information, Inc. JetFlash
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 10d5:5a08 Uni Class Technology Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

For more complete information use the command `lsusb -v`

For information about a specific device on the bus (in this case the attached flash drive) you can indicate the bus#and device# via the -s switch as in:

```
$ lsusb -v -s 2:3

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8564:1000 Transcend Information, Inc. JetFlash
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x8564 Transcend Information, Inc.
  idProduct          0x1000 JetFlash
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 JetFlash
  iProduct                2 Mass Storage Device
  iSerial                 3 DYYUB7GB
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

I've had systems come into the shop that exhibited the problems you outline where the only problem was the ports were packed with dust. A can of compressed air solves this handily. If the ports in question are front or back panel ports on a desktop you can often simply replace the internal harness. If the ports in question are physically attached to the mainboard as is typical in laptops, desoldering/soldering is required (quality of results will be determined by your skill here and are not guaranteed). If it's a chipset problem you are looking at mainboard replacemnent.